# Setting remaining time variable as time from now to midnight?

Tags: javascript, time, timer

Hi I'm new to JavaScript and can't seem to understand how to change this code.

I'd like to change this so the remaining time is from when the users loads the page until midnight. For example if it's 7pm the remaining time will be 5hours 0minutes 0seconds, or if it was 7:45pm remaining time would be 4hours 15minutes 0seconds.

```
function startTimer(start, duration, display) {
    var diff, minutes, seconds;
    function timer(){
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 
        if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(inti);
            document.getElementById("countdownhere").innerHTML
```

EDIT: oops here's the full code, thanks to Jonas W for pointing this out!

```
var d = new Date();

(function($){$.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Countdown Timer!</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;

{$("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=$("#numdays");var theHoursBox=$("#numhours");var theMinsBox=$("#nummins");var theSecsBox=$("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);});</script>

<div class="items-count" id="progress_bar"></div><div id="clock-ticker" class="clearfix"><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numdays">0</span><br><span class="label">Days</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numhours">1</span><br><span class="label">Hours</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="nummins">23</span><br><span class="label">Minutes</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numsecs">36</span><br><span class="label">Seconds</span></div>
```

Comment: try [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) and you can use moment().endOf('day')

Comment: Um theres code missing...

Comment: Jonas w - thank you are right! I've edited and fixed that, I'm sorry! Can you update your answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
var midnight=new Date();
midnight.setHours(0);
midnight.setDate(midnight.getDate()+1);
var display=document.body;
startTimer(new Date(),midnight,display);
```

SetHours sets the Date to todays midnight, then we get the next day...